# flask wtforms triggering a python function with post

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I don't want to use javascript as its probably just a one-off usecase. Here's my code and the problem statement follows.

```
# Form class
class ManageContainers(FlaskForm):
    stop_container = SubmitField('stop')


# HTML Render
{% for i in containers %}
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{ i.short_id }}</th>
                <td>{{ i.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ i.image.tags }}</td>
                <td>{{ i.ports }}</td>
                <td>
                    <form action="#" method="post">
                    {{ form.stop_container() }}
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
{% endfor %}


# Actual app route
@app.route('/list-containers', methods=['POST','GET'])
def index():
    containers_list = client.containers.list(all=False)
    form = ManageContainers()
    if form.is_submitted():
        print("stop the container")
        delete_container(HOW_TO_GET_THIS?)
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('index.html', containers=containers_list, form=form)

def delete_container(container_id):
    container = client.containers.get(container_id)
    container.stop()
    container.remove()
```

I am using docker sdk for python and basically trying to stop / start containers. I am stuck where I want to use that button that says "stop" which will delete the container.

Important - It is actually calling a function like this because I can see "stop the container" in my console. But I don't know how to pass the ID (i.id) of the container while the function is getting called.

Here's a screenshot of what the page actually looks like to save you sometime.
[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hB1ug.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not taking any user input for any fields, I don't think, it's related to WTForms.

You can try the below steps:

1. Create a route for stopping the container:

```py
@app.route('/stop-container/<id>', methods=['POST'])
def stop_container(id):
    delete_container(id)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

2. Change your form to:

```html
<form action={{ url_for('stop_container', id=i.short_id) }} method='post'>
    {{ form.stop_container() }}
</form>
```

Comment: ignore this, i got it to work. Than you very much man, dont know why that didn't occur to me. Cheers!